# Is the element of the exponential of a matrix equal to the exponential of the element?

Tags: matrices, power-series, matrix-exponential

I'm wondering if

$(e^{A})_{ij} = e^{A_{ij}}$

I should prove that

$(e^{A})_{ij} = \left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}\right)_{ij} = (\mathbb{I} + A + \frac{1}{2}A^2 + ...)_{ij} = \mathbb{I}_{ij} + A_{ij} + \frac{1}{2}A_{ih}A_{hj} + ... = \delta_{ij} + A_{ij} + \frac{1}{2}A_{ih}A_{hj} + ... \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(A_{ij})^k}{k!} = e^{A_{ij}}$

But I would say that since $\delta_{ij}$ is not always $1$, but only when $i = j$, then what I'd want to prove is false, since the exponential always needs instead the $1$ at the beginning of the expansion.

Can you tell me if I'm right? Or, else, how would you prove/disprove that?

Comment: It is not true in general. But it is trivially true if $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: @MPW It's not even true in this case. The zero matrix $\mathbf{0}_2$ does not satisfy this requirement.$$\exp{\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\ne\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}=\pmatrix{e^0&e^0\\e^0&e^0}$$

Comment: @A.J. To disprove it, you only need to look at an example. In this case, if you pick a random matrix, it will probably be a counterexample.

Comment: @PeterForeman : Yes, of course you are correct. I was thinking only of the diagonal entries, so $$\exp(\operatorname{diag}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)) = \operatorname{diag}(e^{a_1},e^{a_2},\ldots, e^{a_n})$$ +1 to you for the correction.

Comment: @MPW: I was about to make the same comment as you. D'oh!